# CalDav/CardDav on Open-Xchange

Tags: webdav, caldav, open-xchange

I just installed CalDav/CardDav support to OX 7.6.2 on two machines, one with Debian Stretch (x) and another with Debian Jessie (y). I see this behaviour:

1. I can access (with Dolphin file manger) webdavs://dav.mail2.x.it/servlet/webdav.infostore/ and see files;

   I can access (with Dolphin file manger) webdavs://dav.www.y.it/servlet/webdav.infostore/ and see files;
2. I can acces webdavs://dav.mail2.x.it/ and see caldav, carddav and principals folders;

   I **can't** acces webdavs://dav.www.y.it/ and I cannot see caldav, carddav and principals folders;

I'm quite sure setups are identical on both machines (they are on two different LANs).

I can't see particular errors in OX: how can I find the problem?

Because of point 1 above network configuration seems to be ok and OX and DAV too: why only caldav/carddav doesn't work, while webdav does?

With Dolphin I get the error "File or folder webdavs://dav.www.y.net/ doesn't exist", while with Cadaver command line client:

```
Impossible to access to / (non enabled for WebDAV?): 
405 Method Not Allowed 
Connection to "dav.www.y.net" closed.
```

From OX logs I can see all this:

```
==> /tmp/dav.access.log (on working server) <==
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:53:43 +0200] "PROPFIND /servlet/ HTTP/1.1" 404 412
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:53:44 +0200] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 207 486
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:53:45 +0200] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 207 426
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:53:45 +0200] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 207 426
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:53:46 +0200] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 207 426
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:53:46 +0200] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 207 426

==> /tmp/dav.access.log (on NOT working server) <==
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:51:10 +0200] "PROPFIND /servlet/webdav.infostore HTTP/1.1" 207 1111
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:51:13 +0200] "PROPFIND /servlet/webdav.infostore HTTP/1.1" 207 1111
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:51:15 +0200] "PROPFIND /servlet/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1068
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:51:15 +0200] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 405 312
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:51:16 +0200] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 405 312
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:51:16 +0200] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 405 312
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:51:16 +0200] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 405 312
- - [10/Jul/2015:09:51:17 +0200] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 405 312
```

For configuration I followed this document: http://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?ti...arddav_Bundles

Any idea?

Thanks,
Matteo